# Why poor performance of Netty?

Tags: java, performance, network-programming, netty

i used this  [example](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/http/snoop/package-summary.html)   for performance test

someone says that netty's performance is so fast. It can  process 1,00,000+ concurrent request/sec (check the below links)

http://www.jboss.org/netty/performance/20090303-mheath.html

http://www.jboss.org/netty/performance/20090607-asalihefendic.html

but when i try with this example it's give me only 107 req/sec with 1000 concurrent request

```
ab -n 10000 -c 1000 http://localhost:8080/

Server Software:
Server Hostname:        localhost

Server Port:            8080

Document Path:          /

Document Length:        230 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1000

Time taken for tests:   92.784 seconds

Complete requests:      10000

Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0

Total transferred:      2900000 bytes

HTML transferred:       2300000 bytes

Requests per second:    107.78 [#/sec] (mean)

Time per request:       9278.431 [ms] (mean)

Time per request:       9.278 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)

Transfer rate:          30.52 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

give me suggestion where is the problem

Can someone one please share any web example or reference highlighting performance benchmark of netty.

Comment: A server being able to handle 1,000,000 incoming request/second is not the same as a server being able to handle 1,000,000 incoming requests AND able to produce 1,000 concurrent requests at the same time. You need multiple computers, that aren't the server, to do that kind of test.

Comment: so how can i improve incoming request/sec . if any other server available to handle more incoming request. i also try with nodejs its give me 3000 request/sec

Comment: You haven't even *measured* how many incoming requests/second you can handle (this is not how you test that), so how are you going to improve what you don't know?

Comment: Please ignore above comment 
Thanks for all your reply.
Summary is I am trying to validate netty with large size of concurrent request and confirm its optimum performance on EC2 instance.

Comment: I been trying to execute 1K concurrent request upto 100K total request and see how it performs performance with hello world application. I wanted to collect this statistic and compare with NodeJS therefore I had shared few links above that I had found on internet.
Can someone one please share any web example or reference highlighting performance benchmark of netty like http://zgadzaj.com/benchmarking-nodejs-basic-performance-tests-against-apache-php
Thanks,

Comment: You effectively tested how well you can run `ab` instead of how well `netty` could handle the requests. Your performance was limited by how fast you could send requests rather than how many you could receive. That most of your CPU power is going to generating the requests is also going to make the results useless for how many requests you can handle receiving on that same instance. You need to make the requests from a different computer, and you'll probably need multiple computers to saturate the EC2 instance and see what its capacity really is. Ignore this only if you want to be ignorant.

Comment: The links only claimed they have 100,000 open connections, not 100K requests/sec. The later is near impossible. However 100 req/sec is too low. What's the base number, when concurrency is 1?

Answer (score 6):

You have zero dropped requests and I would benchmark using Siege and compare with other similar setup. Also what kind of system are you using? Probably you also need to increase [file descriptor](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~brecht/servers/openfiles.html) for this to work. Also you need to [configure JVM](http://gleamynode.net/articles/2232/) before doing benchmark. Something along these lines:

```
-server -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
```